# How do I remove flickering from a batch file animation?

Tags: batch-file, animation, cmd, notepad++, flicker

So I've been working on a fake GUI in batch for the ending to a YouTube review I'm working on. It's basically a bunch of box-drawing characters and text that kinda simulates an 80's monochrome terminal. Anyway, the program's got some animation in it that flicker a ton and briefly blinks when I move to the next stage of sections that aren't animated. The way I got the frames set up is, well, just the GUI written with box-drawing characters and text forming the entire screen. The animations are set up so that after one frame, 'ping localhost' is used as the timer, followed by 'cls', followed by the next frame and so on. I assume that the 'cls' is what's causing all the flickering. Normally I'd be fine with the flickering as I believe it adds to the feel of something out of the 80's, however as I plan on using this in a YouTube video for all of the world to see, I don't want to possibly be the reason someone has an epileptic episode. Is there another way to eliminate the flicker or another way to animate this so that the flicker doesn't happen? I already have the entire program finished and would hate to have to throw it all away. Other information is that I'm on Windows 10 and used Notepad++ to make this thing.

Comment: It pays to research methods before scripting. Without including a minimum reproducible example of the method your using, or what version/s of windows you want to use it on, little help can be offered on how to modify your existing script to reduce or eliminate flicker

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. Unfortunately, an example of the code in question is 1194 lines long.

Comment: You're right that it's the `cls` that's causing the flickering. Since you're using Windows 10, you can use VT100 escape sequences to move the cursor back to the beginning of the window, which will have the same effect as `cls` but without actually clearing the screen. Then you just write over what's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark)'s comment -

Virtual terminal codes are supported in windows 10 only

The Escape Control Character can be defined by parsing over The Prompt $E command. One method is:

```bat
 for /F "delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$E# & for %%a in (1) do rem"') do set "\E=%%a"
```

Another, simpler method is:

```bat
 for /F %%a in ('Echo prompt $E ^|cmd') do set "\E=%%a"
```

The vast majority of sequence's [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) are supported

Virtual terminal codes are also supported by the `Type` command, allowing efficient screen updates by outputting changed cells to a file, then typing the file to screen.
*Note: Issues can occur when using type with UTF-8 Codepage characters, even with the correct codepage set - to avoid those issues, explicity redirect the type file command to `Con`. IE:*

```
Type "filename.ext" > Con
```

After defining the Escape character `%\E%`, The console cursor can be suppressed using:

```bat
<nul set /P "=%\E%[?25l"
```

And Enabled with:

```bat
<nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25h"
```

Individual cells can be cleared using:

```bat
rem /* for current cell location */
<nul Set /P "=%\E%[1X"
rem /* for a cell located at substituted y x coordinate value */
<nul Set /P "=%\E%[y;xH%\E%[1X"
```

An example script that produce a flicker free animation with a consistent frame rate can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68483400/12343998)