# Is it possible to reliably run an ASCII text based video from cmd prompt?

Tags: batch-file

**Okay this one is a doozy**

Let's start with what I have and what I have done then the issues I am having.

---

First I took a video and extracted the frames with FFMPEG which left me with a ton of frames. As we all know CMD can't do much with jpg files. So I used a program that allowed me to convert them to ASCII. With a little batch magic, I got something working to mass convert all of the images.

---

**Code for that**

**JPEGCompiler.bat**

```bat
@echo off
set /p video=Drag Video into Console (Currently Limited to C:/): 
ffmpeg -i %video% -an -f image2 "output_%%05d.jpg"
```

(This works with the help of FFMPEG )

---

I then had to create a list of the files for the next batch to grab. This wasn't super difficult.

**Jpglist.bat**

---

```bat
dir /B *.jpg >> JPEGList.txt
```

And finally, a way of automating everything with an increasing variable.

**JPEGCompiler.bat**

```bat
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set cycles=0

cd> CD.txt

for /F "delims=" %%i in (CD.txt) do set "CD=%%i"
for /F "delims=" %%i in (CDD.txt) do set "CD=%%i"

type cd.txt | sed "s/C://">> CDD.txt

:startpoint
set "xprvar="
for /F "skip=%cycles% delims=" %%i in (JPEGList.txt) do if not defined xprvar set "xprvar=%%i"

set /a cycles=cycles+1
ascii-image-converter.exe %CDD%%xprvar% --save-txt .

goto startpoint
```

---

Using what I learned previously with the increasing variable, I used the same method to grab all of the text files and order them into a list for CMD

**Textlist.bat**

---

```bat
dir /B *.txt >> TextList.txt
```

**That brings me to this point.**

**TEXTCompiler.bat**

---

```bat
@echo off
color 02
set cycles=0

:startpoint


for /F "skip=%cycles% delims=" %%i in (TextList.txt) do set "xprvar=%%i"&goto nextline
:nextline

set /a cycles=cycles+1

type %xprvar%

call waitfor

goto startpoint
```

---

(`call waitfor` is an attempt at using precise timing but it didn't really make a difference with or without it I get a little more control but the same issues are present)

[image: Output frames]

The code runs fine but there are some issues. With the `cls` command its like it will clear the screen way too fast and the video gets slowly and occasionally eaten from the bottom up. However, without that `cls`, the ASCII art video scrolls like a boss.

There are also issues with sync from the original video. (bat plays fast or slow depending on how it's feeling?)

So my question is, **is there a way to sync fps**? What's the best way to go about this?

This playback can be seen [here!](https://twitter.com/i/status/1417349692757790721)

[Playback without CLS](https://twitter.com/i/status/1417412310151450628)

Comment: Instead of [begging us not to down-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68452225/4), you should better put in the effort to make your question clearer and on-topic; "what's the best way" is mostly too broad; please consult [ask]…

Answer (score 0):

There are two key things you should research:

`1)` Implement frame rate in Batch.

- See Dave Benhams [Snake.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741) for a good example.

`2)` Update console Display without using CLS

- [The easiest solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281635/how-do-i-remove-flickering-from-a-batch-file-animation/65287064#65287064) for doing so involves using [Virtual terminal sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences), however they are only available on windows 10.

Note also:
Goto and call are inefficient and should be avoided for any application where a fast and consistent framerate is desired. Use instead a codeblock contained within an infinite for /L loop.

An example that generates an animation:

```bat
@Echo off & CD /D "%~dp0"
 For /f %%e in ('Echo Prompt $E^|cmd') Do set "\E=%%e"
 <nul Set /P "=%\E%[?25l"
 Cls & Mode 90,40
 Set /A "Files=0","FC=1"

 Echo(Choose Framerate: %= Defaults to 25 fps after 4 seconds =%
 Echo(1] 50fps
 Echo(2] 33fps
 Echo(3] 25fps
 Echo(4] 20fps
 Echo(5] 17fps
 Echo(6] 14fps
 Echo(7] 12.5fps
 Echo(8] 10fps
 Echo(9] 6fps

 For /f "delims=" %%G in ('Choice /T 4 /N /C:123456789 /D 3')Do (
  If %%G LSS 8 Set /A "delay=%%G+1"
  If %%G==8 Set "delay=10"
  If %%G==9 Set "delay=16"
 )

 Cls
 Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

 For %%i in (5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5)Do (
  Set /A Files+=1
  Call :CreateCube %%i "infile!Files!.txt"
 )

 For /L %%i in ()Do (
  %= Calculate time elapsed in centiseconds =%
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:.," %%a in ("!time: =0!") do set /a "t2=(((1%%a*60)+1%%b)*60+1%%c)*100+1%%d-36610100, tDiff=t2-t1"
  if !tDiff! lss 0 set /a tDiff+=24*60*60*100
  %= update frame if framerate delay expired =%
  if !tDiff! geq !delay! (
   %= use modulus based increment to cycle through file count =%
   Set /A "FC=FC %% Files + 1"
   %= Assign offset based on current filecount =%
   If !FC! GTR 10 (If !Offset! GTR 1 Set /A "Offset-=1")Else Set "offset=!FC!"
   %= affect offset; Clear screen to cursor pos =%
   <nul set /P "=%\E%[!offset!G%\E%[!Offset!d%\E%[1J"
   %= read file; clear line; offset cursor; output line; emit linefeed - Redirecting block to con =%
   (For /f "Delims=" %%G in (infile!FC!.txt)Do <nul set /P "=%\E%[K%\E%[!offset!G%%G%\E%[E") > Con
   %= Clear remainder of screen =%
   <nul Set /P "=%\E%[0J"
   %= Update previous time =%
   set /a t1=t2
  )
 )

:CreateCube <size>
:# golfed script for outputting a shaded multi color cube
:# https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224741/92319
@echo off&Cls&Set $=Set &CHCP 65001 > nul
If "%~1"=="" (Echo(%~n0 Integer Outfile.ext&Exit /B)
If "%~2"=="" (Echo(%~n0 Integer Outfile.ext&Exit /B)
%$%/A x=%1,h=x*2,z=0
%$%F=For /L %%a in (1 1 &%$%P=^<nul set/p &%$%C= If %%y LEQ %1 
((%f:a=y%!h!)Do (%$%/a w=x-z
%F%!w!)Do %P%"=%\E%C"
%F%!z!)Do%C%(%P%"=%\E%[38;2;;120;%%a0m_|")Else %P%=%\E%[4m%\E%[38;2;120;;%%a0m\\%\E%[0m
%F%%1)Do%C%(%P%"=%\E%[38;2;120;;%%a0m▲▼")Else %P%=%\E%[38;2;;120;%%a0m_\
%C:EQ=SS%(%$%/A z+=1)Else%C:If=If not%%$%/A z-=1)&Echo(%\E%[0m))>"%~2"
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the input and will see what I can come up with!